# Cannot update file upload form, laravel form binding

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Hello I have to edit and update a form with file upload. When i edit the other fields and also i upload a photo it works. but if i edit other fields without uploading a photo it shows error " Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object "

my view

```
{{ Form::model($layer, array('method'=>'PATCH', 'route'=>array('edit-layer-patch', $layer->id), 'files'=> true)) }}


<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image" value="{{ $layer->img_path }}" class="form-control" onchange="readURL(this);" id="image" accept="image/*" />
    {{ HTML::image('uploads/'. $layer->img_path, 'your image', array('id' => 'blah', 'width'=>150, 'height' => 100)) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="layer_name">Layer Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="layer_name" value="{{ $layer->layer_name }}" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">    
<label for="select_user">Select User</label>
<select name="select_user" class="form-control">
    <option value="{{ $layer->user->id }}">{{ $layer->user->firstname }}</option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->firstname }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">    
<label for="select_style">Select Style</label>
<select name="select_style" class="form-control">
    <option value="{{ $layer->style->id }}">{{ $layer->style->style_name }}</option>
    @foreach($styles as $style)
    <option value="{{ $style->id }}">{{ $style->style_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">    
<label for="select_category">Select Category</label>
<select name="select_category" class="form-control">
    @if(!empty($layer->category->category_name))
    <option value="{{ $layer->category->id }}">{{ $layer->category->category_name }}</option>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    @else
    <option value="">Deleted</option>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    @endif

</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="published">Published</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="1"  name="published" value="{{ $layer->published }}" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="default">Default</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="1"  name="default" value="{{ $layer->default }}" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('layers') }}">Cancel</a>
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

my controller

```
public function edit($id){

    $image = Input::file('image');

    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $destinationPath = 'uploads/';

    $layer = Layer::find($id);

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Layer::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::route('edit-layer')->withErrors($validator)->with('message', 'Ups something happened');
    }else{  
     //Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);
        Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);



        if(Input::has('image')){
            $layer->user_id       = Input::get('select_user');
            $layer->style_id      = Input::get('select_style');
            $layer->category_id   = Input::get('select_category');
            $layer->layer_name    = Input::get('layer_name');
            $layer->published     = Input::get('published');
            $layer->default       = Input::get('default');
            $layer->save(); 
        }else{
            $layer->user_id       = Input::get('select_user');
            $layer->style_id      = Input::get('select_style');
            $layer->category_id   = Input::get('select_category');
            $layer->layer_name    = Input::get('layer_name');
            $layer->published     = Input::get('published');
            $layer->default       = Input::get('default');
            $layer->img_path = $filename;
            $layer->save(); 
        }

        return Redirect::route('layers')->with('message','Layer Updated');
    }
}
```

Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do this:

```
$image = Input::file('image');
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
```

Even if you don't upload an image (ergo `$image` is `null`)

You need to move all the image related stuff into the `if(Input::has('image'))` check

```
public function edit($id){

    $destinationPath = 'uploads/';
    $layer = Layer::find($id);
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Layer::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('edit-layer')->withErrors($validator)->with('message', 'Ups something happened');
    }else{  

        if(Input::has('image')){
            $image = Input::file('image');

            $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

            Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

            // ...
        }else{
            // ...
        }

        return Redirect::route('layers')->with('message','Layer Updated');
    }
}
```

#### Update

*from the comments*

`admin/layers/%7Bid%7D/edit` is actually `admin/layers/{id}/edit`.

Looks like the validation fails and it goes to `Redirect::route('edit-layer')` which is **missing the id parameter**

Do this:

```
return Redirect::route('edit-layer', array($id))->withErrors($validator)->with('message', 'Ups something happened');
```

Comment: i did that but still it shows that "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException"

Comment: Well that's probably a new problem. Does the redirect happen or does the error show before?

Comment: it happens the redirect too, when i click submit. it adds some percentage a different url from update(when i upload a photo) admin/layers/%7Bid%7D/edit

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the (relevant) code of your routes file?

Comment: Alright, suppose you are going to edit a form with laravel. By edit i mean update, which take two methods. edit and update. in update method i have the code i showed it above. when i submit the form without uploading a photo, i mean editing other fields than photo, it doesnt work. it shows this message. "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException" . i can update it only by uploading a photo.

Comment: Yes but I need to see your routes.

Comment: these are my routes, "Route::get('layers/{id}/edit', array('as' => 'edit-layer','uses' => 'LayerController@edit'));
  Route::patch('layers/{id}', array('as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'LayerController@update'));"

Comment: Think I found the source of the problem. See the updated answer

Comment: It doesnt show error anymore, but it doesnt update the form. it also redirects to the same page, without changes, even if i upload a photo.

Comment: Thank you, i got the solution. the error is when i validate the form. i removed the validation and it works. it updates the form with and without uploading the photo. Thank you very much. I have only 13 reputation , i cant upvote your answer

Comment: That's ok. But you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. And if I were you, don't just give up on the validation. Try to find out why it fails when it shouldn't...

Comment: I fixed the error. the validation showed me error because i had the input file required and thats why. (facepalm)

Comment: Hahaha. Learning means making mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all of that image stuff inside of the `if(Input::has('image'))`  statement.